# Login auth for existing user not working correct for existing and non existing user in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am working on login panel with custom login after successfull user registeration with in table while trying to login after validating email and password in correct format it unabling to check auth condition as i have used auth library.While registering user i am entering md5 format password then how i can check email and md5 password exist with in database.Right now only else part is executing for corret credentials.

Controller Code:

```
public function login_student(Request $request){
$rules = array(
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
        );
         $validator = Validator::make(Input::all() , $rules);
          if ($validator->fails()) {
             return Redirect::to('log')->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::except('password'));  
          }else{
          $email = Input::get('email');
          $pass = md5($request->input['password']);
          if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'),'password' => $pass])) {
              echo "Welcome User";
              exit;
                } 
                else {
                echo "Please enter correct details to login";
                  exit;
             }
             }
       }
```

Comment: with `Auth` check pass with `bcrypt` so no md5 works

Comment: no iam using md5 with in register an trying to match that password using auth at login

Answer (score 0):

Since you used an Auth library, the `Auth` service will handle the encryption of passwords.

Therefore you must replace the following line:

`$pass = md5($request->input['password']);`

To:

`$pass = $request->input('password');`

Comment: I have change it to  $pass = $request->input['password']; still iam getting same issue as i have defined use Auth in top of file with in controller

Comment: No. Laravel will load your authentication library and use its login function (which must handle the encryption). Which library did you use?

Comment: use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;use Auth; and i have also added auth from artisan but by default i am trying use this in my custom login function

Comment: Noticed a slight mistake in your code. Password must be retrieved through the `input` function rather than the array. Try the code again and let me know.

Comment: Now i have use $email = Input::get('email');
           $pass = Input::get('password');
    if(Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $pass))) {
              echo "Welcome User";
              exit;
                } 
                else {
                echo "Please enter correct details to login";
   exit;
    } it stills gives same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Auth:: guard()?

```
if (Auth::guard()->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {

/////////////////
}
```

Comment: use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;  i have use this but it also executing else part for correct credentials

Comment: are you trying to override default login function?

Comment: i have created my cutom login function and trying to validate and authenticate for check user

Comment: By default laravel looks for login() method from AuthenticatesUsers class so make sure your method is overriding the deafult login method.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
$user = \App\Models\User::where([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => md5($request->password)
    ])->first();

if ($user) {
   echo "Welcome User";
   exit;
} 
else{
   echo "Please enter correct details to login";
   exit;
}
```

Comment: i have used this but its giving issue i have updated config auth with model path and in model defined namespace .Class 'App\Models\User' not found

Comment: so where is your `User` class use this location

Comment: i have created models folder inside app and put user model with in model folder and change path to \App\Models\User in both controller and config/auth file to model but still giving issue

Comment: not do that just find the `User.php` folder and given that path only no need to create folder for that

Comment: actually my controller name is same and model also and its giving issue (Cannot declare class Tutoring\Http\Controllers\User because the name is already in use)

Comment: one `User.php` file have in `App` Folder not in controller so check in `App folder` and use  `App\User`

Comment: i have rename my controller with users now still iam getting same as i have change path with in config/auth and controller and in model also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182323/discussion-between-bhargav-chudasama-and-priya-negi).

Comment: $user = \App\User::where([
      'email' => $request->email,
      'password' => md5($request->password)
     ])->first();

    if ($user) {
       echo "Welcome User";
       exit;
    } 
    else{
       echo "Please enter correct details to login";
       exit;
    }  i have use this but still getting issue

Comment: i have send message in chat so possible with chat so we will talk there